# how do you layer two procedural textures while keeping opacity?

Tags: procedural, shader-nodes

Trying to figure out how to layer these two textures created from nodes while keeping the opacity. I've tried using mix shader/ mix rgb/ combine rgb nodes but Im fairly new to texturing so I could be plugging them in all wrong. I just want the pillow to have the black gradient over the yellow/gold part.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to transfer the darks from the gradient, use a MixRGB node set to "multiply". If you want pure black transfer, make sure the mix factor slider is all the way at 1 (it's less than 1 in the image):

[image: Multi]

Since your gradient texture is black and white, you could also use it as a mask, to mix your cushion texture with another color or texture (texture not shown) - Just connect the "other" texture to the open socket (the one that's currently occupied by the orange color):

[image: Multi2]

Lastly, if you want the 2 materials to have different shading properties, connect the shaders (BSDF's) through a Mix Shader - Because there is no such option as "multiply" for the mix shader, using the B&W texture as a mask is advised - you can still use it as a mask (mix factor) for itself if you want (see below):

[image: Multi3]